# Difference between Mono#then and Mono#and?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Given the following monos:

```java
Mono<Void> mono1 = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
    System.out.println("sleep1");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    System.out.println("mono1");
});
Mono<Void> mono2 = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
    System.out.println("mono2");
});
Mono<Void> mono3 = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
    System.out.println("mono3");
});
```

Both:

```java
mono1
        .then(mono2)
        .then(mono3)
        .block();
```

And:

```java
mono1
        .and(mono2)
        .and(mono3)
        .block();
```

Have the same output:

```
sleep
mono1
mono2
mono3
```

What's the difference between [`Mono#then`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) and [`Mono#and`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#and-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) in this case?

---

From https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#which-operator:

> [If you] have a sequence but [you are] not interested in values and [you] want to switch to another Mono at the end, [use] `Mono#then(mono)`.
>
> [If you] want to combine publishers by coordinating their termination from 1 Mono and any source into a Mono, [use] `Mono#and`.

This doesn't help me finding a case where `#and` and `#then` would behave differently unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mono#and` just "joins the termination signals from current mono and another source into the returned void mono". It always returns `Mono<Void>` and only lets you coordinate termination of two `Mono`s.

`Mono#then` lets you chain two `Mono`s together and the final result will be determined by the `Mono` passed as a parameter. In this sense, `Mono#then` is a more primitive version of `Mono#flatMap`, the only difference is that inside of `Mono#flatMap` you have access to the result of the previous `Mono` in a chain that you can transform into another `Mono` instance.

In addition to that, with `Mono#then` the operations will be executed sequentially, while with `Mono#and` there is no guarantee of ordering (at least from the documentation).